# Getting the Record That Joined 2 Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Alright so I have a simple has_many :through relationship in Rails 3.1

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invites

  [...]
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invites
  has_many :events, :through => :invites

  [...]
end

class Invite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :event

  [...]
end
```

To get all of user's events I do

```
@events = current_account.events
```

How can I get the record that joined the two tables (ie. the invite row) without running a query for each event? Or at least one column from the Invite record I need to reference?

Using :include => :invites includes ALL invites for each event. I just need the one the join was done on. I scoured Google and couldn't find anything. I feel like this should be a pretty straightforward thing to do. What am I missing?

Comment: So do you want the invite that links the account to the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fetch them from the other side:

```
Event
  .includes ( :invites => :account )
  .where    ( :invites => {:accounts => {:id => current_account.id }} )
```

Be careful, in the `where` clause the symbols must be plural (table names) whereas in the `includes` clause the symbols refer to associations (plural if `has_many`, singular if `belongs_to`). BTW, your `Invites` model should be singular (`Invite`) according to rails conventions.

Comment: Great thanks!

And invite is the model name. The 's' was just typo.